# How to attach second external monitor on an Ubuntu laptop with one VGA out (for 3 screens in total)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I run Ubuntu (11.04). I have a monitor connected to the laptop, so two screens, all works fine.

I would like to be able to connect a **second external monitor**, so I can get **three screens**.

My laptop only has one VGA out, which is being for the first external monitor. I have a spare USB slot. Is there a reliable solution that will work on a Linux machine, maybe using the extra USB slot?

**EDIT**: I've just stumbled upon the [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/?productTabs=1) which seems ideal but it only lists support for Windows & Mac. Anyone know if this or anything similar is supported for Linux?

Comment: You can use a USB graphics adapter, but I don't know how the linux driver situation is. They work fine with Windows.

Comment: The DualHeadToGo would be cheaper and match your requirements better, the analogue version will take a single VGA output and split it over two monitors, so two 1280x1024 displays will just look like one big 2560x1024 display. Note, the Matrox page you linked to does say Linux is supported at the bottom. *8')

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use one of the USB-to-VGA adapters listed under "Confirmed working adapters" on this web page:

USB-to-VGA on Linux
  http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/HowTo/AddVGAAdapter

Below, I've included images of two adapters that are identified on the above page as "confirmed working..."

Sweex KB100050:
[image]

Startech.com USB2VGA:
[image]